# Prove the existence (or well-definedness) of the induced connection in tensor bundle

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-bundles, smooth-manifolds, connections

Given a connection $\nabla$ on a vector bundle $E$ over a smooth manifold $M$, we know there is a unique extension of $\nabla$ to all tensor bundles of $E$ that satisfies Leibniz rule and contraction. I am going to prove this.

We can first define the connection on the dual space of $E$ using the formula forced by the axioms above. Then the rest is essentially just proving one lemma:

Given two bundles $E$, $F$ on $M$ and connections on $E$ and $F$, both denoted by $\nabla$, then there is a unique connection $\nabla$ on $E\otimes F$ such that 
$$\nabla_X(s_E\otimes s_F)=\nabla_X s_E\otimes s_F+s_E\otimes \nabla_X s_F$$

I tried to invoke the universal property of tensor product as usual, to use bilinearity to prove well-definedness. However this tensor product of sections is not the strict tensor product in linear algebra tense (it takes tensor product pointwise, and it cannot be understood as a tensor product of two $\mathbb R$-vector spaces. It can be tensor product of $C^\infty(M)$ modules though, but $\nabla_X$ is not $C^\infty$ linear). So I get in problem here, and I ask for a conceptual way to show why $\nabla_X$ is a well defined map from the space of sections of $E\otimes F$ to itself.

Comment: Every section $\sigma$ of $E \otimes F$ is a finite sum of sections of the form $s_E \otimes s_F$ (at least locally). You can just take your definition of the connection on sections of the form $s_E \otimes s_F$ and extend linearly. When you say you want to prove well-definedness, do you mean that you want to prove that writing $\sigma$ as such a sum in two different ways yields the same result?

Comment: Yes. And this is where we usually invoke the universal property of tensor products, because there is no canonical way to write down an element in tensor product spaces.

Comment: Why can't sections of $E \otimes F$ be viewed as the tensor product of $\mathbb{R}$-vector spaces $C^\infty(E) \otimes_\mathbb{R} C^\infty(F)$? Perhaps I'm overlooking something, but if it can be viewed that way, can't you then view the connection as an $\mathbb{R}$-bilinear map $C^\infty(E) \times C^\infty(F) \to C^\infty(E) \otimes C^\infty(F)$, and then apply the universal property to conclude the connection factors through $C^\infty(E) \otimes C^\infty(F)$?

Comment: There is a fact that $C^\infty (E\otimes F)\cong C^\infty(E)\otimes_{C^\infty(M)} C^\infty(F)$. It is not a subspace of $ C^\infty(E)\otimes_\mathbb R C^\infty(F)$, but instead a quotient space of it.

Comment: Simplistically, an operator $\nabla$ is a connection on a vector bundle, if the following hold: 1) $\nabla_{fX+Y}s = f\nabla_Xs + \nabla_Ys$ and 2) $\nabla_X (fs + t) = (Xf)s + f\nabla_X s + \nabla_Xt$. Now all you need to do is to verify that the operator on the right side satisfies these properties and therefore defines a valid connection on the tensor bundle.

Comment: Sometimes, using universal properties is a better way to understand things, but sometimes I find them more confusing than helpful.

Answer (score 3):

It seems to me that people usually include the $\mathbb{R}$-linearity as part of the definition (correct me if I'm wrong); i.e. define $\nabla$ on the simple tensors by the product rule above, and then extend it linearly over $\mathbb{R}$ to the whole space $C^{\infty}(E\otimes F)$.

Actually, due to the fact that $C^{\infty}(E\otimes F)\simeq C^{\infty}(E)\otimes_{C^{\infty}(M)}C^{\infty}(F)$ which OP has mentioned in the comment above, it follows that additivity (i.e.
\begin{align}
\nabla_X(s\otimes t+s'\otimes t')=\nabla_X(s\otimes t)+\nabla_X(s'\otimes t')
\end{align}
which is weaker than $\mathbb{R}$-linearity) is sufficient.

With this in mind, here is an alternative proof, which is essentially a direct computation, though perhaps it may look less elegant.

Let $A\in C^{\infty}(E\otimes F)$. Such $A$ can be expressed as a finite sum of simple tensors, though not uniquely in general. So we want to show that if it can be written in the following two ways
\begin{align}
A=\sum_is_i\otimes t_i=\sum_j\tilde{s}_j\otimes\tilde{t}_j
\end{align}
(the number of summands in these two expressions may be different in general), then
\begin{align}
\nabla_X\left(\sum_is_i\otimes t_i\right)
=\nabla_X\left(\sum_j\tilde{s}_j\otimes\tilde{t}_j\right) & & (*)
\end{align}
Let $(e_{\alpha})$ and $(\epsilon_{\beta})$ be smooth local frames for $E$ and $F$ respectively. Then one can write
\begin{align}
s_i=s_i^{\alpha}e_{\alpha},\qquad
t_j=t_j^{\beta}\epsilon_{\beta},\qquad
\tilde{s}_i=\tilde{s}_i^{\alpha}e_{\alpha},\qquad
\tilde{t}_j=\tilde{t}_j^{\beta}\epsilon_{\beta}
\end{align}
(Einstein summation convention is assumed.) Then we will have
\begin{align}
\sum_is_i\otimes t_i
=\left(\sum_is_i^{\alpha}t_i^{\beta}\right)e_{\alpha}\otimes\epsilon_{\beta},
\qquad
\sum_j\tilde{s}_j\otimes\tilde{t}_j
=\left(\sum_j\tilde{s}_j^{\alpha}\tilde{t}_j^{\beta}\right)e_{\alpha}\otimes\epsilon_{\beta}
\end{align}
Since $\{e_{\alpha}\otimes\epsilon_{\beta}\}$ is a smooth local frame for $E\otimes F$, by uniqueness of local components we must have
\begin{align}
\sum_is_i^{\alpha}t_i^{\beta}=\sum_j\tilde{s}_j^{\alpha}\tilde{t}_j^{\beta} & & (1)
\end{align}
Taking exterior derivative we then have
\begin{align}
\sum_i\left(t_i^{\beta}ds_i^{\alpha}+s_i^{\alpha}dt_i^{\beta}\right)
=\sum_j\left(\tilde{t}_j^{\beta}d\tilde{s}_j^{\alpha}
+\tilde{s}_j^{\alpha}d\tilde{t}_j^{\beta}\right) & & (2)
\end{align}
Now let $\omega_{\alpha}^{\beta}$ and $\theta_{\alpha}^{\beta}$ be the connection 1-forms of $\nabla^E$ and $\nabla^F$ respectively, so that e.g.
\begin{align}
\nabla_X s_i=\left[Xs_i^{\alpha}+s_i^{\beta}\omega_{\beta}^{\alpha} (X)\right]e_{\alpha} & & (3)
\end{align}
and similar identities hold for $\nabla_Xt_i$, $\nabla_X\tilde{s}_j$ and $\nabla_X\tilde{t}_j$. Then we can compute
\begin{align}
&\nabla_X\left(\sum_is_i\otimes t_i\right) \\
%%%
&=\sum_i\left(\nabla_Xs_i\otimes t_i+s_i\otimes\nabla_Xt_i\right) \\
%%%
&=\underbrace{\left(\sum_i\left((Xs_i^{\alpha})t_i^{\beta}
+s_i^{\alpha}(Xt_i^{\beta})\right)\right)}_{=:I}e_{\alpha}\otimes\epsilon_{\beta}
+\underbrace{\left(\sum_is_i^{\gamma}t_i^{\beta}\right)}_{=:II}
\omega_{\gamma}^{\alpha}(X)e_{\alpha}\otimes\epsilon_{\beta}
+\underbrace{\left(\sum_is_i^{\alpha}t_i^{\gamma}\right)}_{=:III}
\theta_{\gamma}^{\beta}(X)e_{\alpha}\otimes\epsilon_{\beta}
\end{align}
where the first step follows by additivity and product rule, while the second step is obtained by substitution of (3) and rearranging the terms.

Now $\nabla_X\left(\sum_j\tilde{s}_j\otimes\tilde{t}_j\right)$ will have the same expression, except that all of the $s_i,t_i$ are replaced by $\tilde{s}_j,\tilde{t}_j$; says
\begin{align}
\nabla_X\left(\sum_j\tilde{s}_j\otimes\tilde{t}_j\right)
=\tilde{I}\cdot e_{\alpha}\otimes\epsilon_{\beta}
+\tilde{II}\cdot \omega_{\gamma}^{\alpha}(X)e_{\alpha}\otimes\epsilon_{\beta}
+\tilde{III}\cdot \theta_{\gamma}^{\beta}(X)e_{\alpha}\otimes\epsilon_{\beta}
\end{align}
Then:

- By (2), we have $I=\tilde{I}$.
- By (1), we have $II=\tilde{II}$ and $III=\tilde{III}$.

Hence, (*) holds as desired.

Answer (score 0):

Here one should invoke the universal property for [balanced maps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product_of_modules):

view $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}(E)$ as left $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}(M)$ module, and $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}(F)$ as right $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}(M)$ (which we of course can, since everything is commutative).

Check that for your formula $\nabla((f \cdot s_E) \otimes s_F) = \nabla (s_E \otimes (s_F \cdot f))$ and bi-additivity hold, so that by the universal property we get a map of **abelian groups**: $$\mathcal{C}^{\infty}(E \otimes F) =\mathcal{C}^{\infty}(E) \otimes_{\mathcal{C}^{\infty}(M)} \mathcal{C}^{\infty}(F) \to \mathcal{C}^{\infty} (\wedge^1 M \otimes (E \otimes F)).$$Here we use the fact that for a commutative ring universality with respect to bilinear maps and with respect to balanced maps yields isomorphic objects (see, for instance, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/184627/equality-of-two-notions-of-tensor-products-over-a-commutative-ring?rq=1)).

Then one checks by hand that actually the map is $\mathbb{R}$-linear and Leibniz rule holds, thus we have a connection.